# If value like element in list in Python

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, list

If value like element in list then print that element in list.

```
val = 'https://www.google.com/search?q=google'

elements = ['google.com', 'bing.com', 'yahoo.com']
```

I want the result `google.com`.

My code:

```
if val in elements:
    print(elements)
```

I know `print(elements)` will print all the elements in the list. But can I just print the one element it matches to?

I want to do `val like in elements` print the element it matches to

Comment: You can iterate over elements and do `if val in element: ...`

Comment: @zamir, I did that and it didnt return any thing

Comment: What is if val in elements ? It will always return None

Comment: You're doing the opposite validation. The <em>Element</em> is in the value, not the other way around. Try searching each element in your value, instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this.

```
for el in elements:
    if el in val:
        print(el)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have the for loop backwards in your step above. Since the value in elements are the subsection of val you need to iterate through elements are check if it is in val.

```
for i in elements:
    if i in val:
    print(i)
```